# Discord.py bot saying message details (such as message id, channel id, author etc) rather than the content of the message

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

For reference, i'm very new to python so I don't know much. I am creating a very simple madlibs game for a discord bot im working on. I have it ask questions, get the user response onto a variable, ask another question etc. At the end, it prints out the "story" using the user responses. My problem is that instead of writing the actual contents of the message, the bot writes out all the message details, such as the user id, channel id, and that sort of stuff.

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "madlibs" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("what dog do you want")
        dog = await client.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("where do you want to live")
        live = await client.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("what car do you want")
        car = await client.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("what house do you want")
        house = await client.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("Your dog is " + str(dog) + ", live in " + str(live) + ", have a " + str(car) + " , and your house is a " + str(house) + ".")```

I'm wondering how to make it say the actual content of the user message, not the message details. Other than that, it looks like it works fine.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content of a message in discord.py by simply doing `message.content`. For example,

```py
dog = (await client.wait_for("message")).content
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error "AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'content'"

Comment: @acid_ic Sorry, forgot parentheses